# Better way of doing a Null check in Dataweave Mule

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I usually do a null check in Dataweave, as below,

> { payload.variableA when payload != null otherwise null }

But one of my Collegue has suggested me to use default {} to reduce the null checks, like below,

```
%var x = payload default {}
{
payload.variableA
}
```

As it improves readability, especially in complex transformations.

But is it really a good practice to do this way? Will it cause any issues, like creating unnecessary empty objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `payload.variableA` should return null when payload is null. You don't need to do a check on that. Attempting to access a key on a null object returns null rather than throwing something like a null-pointer exception you might be used to.

You can think of `default` as the null-coalesce operator for dataweave. You can set it to an empty object, a default value, etc etc.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-cookbook-defaults

The default operator behaves the same in DW1 and DW2.

Comment: Got it. But let's say if we want to access deeper children like:
{
x: payload.variableA.variableB ,
y: payload.variableA.variableB.variableC
z: payload.variableA
}
then don't we have to do a Null check?
instead, do you think we can do something like this:

%var temp = payload.variableA default {}

{
x: temp.variableB ,
y: temp.variableB.variableC
z: temp
}

Will Y still work?

Comment: @RohitKakani no. You could literally do this `{ a: null.A.A.A }` and it would just yield `{a: null }` without any errors. The only way to distinguish between a null and 'this key doesn't even exist' is to do a check like `{ test: "key presset" when null.A.A.A? otherwise "key missing" }`. This gets you 'key missing'. So you have `?` to check if a key exists. Ultimately data-weave does not care if the object you're trying to access a key on is null, and it doesn't care if the key exists or not - it will return null in those cases. Now, it does care if you try and do something like coerce.

Comment: Understood. Thank you!

Comment: is this the same with flowVars:
can we replace this:
variableA: null when flowVars.variableB == null otherwise flowVars.variableB
with
variableA: flowVars.variableB